# Using radio button meta data from a custom meta box

Tags: posts, plugin-development, metabox, post-meta, radio

Very new to attempting PHP and am hacking together my first plugin using tutorials..

I have a custom meta box with a Yes/No radio button on all WordPress pages (in the editor).

**EDIT-** I removed the original code. See below.

So.. my question is, how do I check to see *which* of the two buttons is checked using an if() statement? I plan on appending a script to WordPress pages that have 'yes' selected. I'm simply not sure which value I should be looking for, or how to call it out.

**EDIT-**

This is what I'm now using with no luck.

Current code:

```
<?php
}

/**
 * Adds a meta box to the post editing screen
 */
function prfx_custom_meta() {
add_meta_box( 'prfx_meta', __( 'Meta Plugin', 'prfx-textdomain' ), 'prfx_meta_callback', 'page', 'side', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prfx_custom_meta' );

function is_edit_page($new_edit = null){
global $pagenow;
//make sure we are on the backend
if (!is_admin()) return false;


if($new_edit == "edit")
    return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php',  ) );
elseif($new_edit == "new") //check for new post page
    return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post-new.php' ) );
else //check for either new or edit
    return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) );
}

/**
* Outputs the content of the meta box
*/
function prfx_meta_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'prfx_nonce' );
$prfx_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
?>

<p>
<span class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Is this a thank you page?', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></span>
<div class="prfx-row-content">
    <label for="meta-radio-one">
        <input type="radio" name="meta-radio" id="meta-radio-one" value="radio-one" <?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-radio'] ) ) checked($prfx_stored_meta['meta-radio'][0], 'radio-one' ); ?>>
        <?php _e( 'Yes', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="meta-radio-two">
        <input type="radio" name="meta-radio" id="meta-radio-two" value="radio-two" <?php 
        if (is_edit_page('new')) echo "checked"; 
        else if (isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['meta-radio'] ) ) checked($prfx_stored_meta['meta-radio'][0], 'radio-two' ); 
        else  echo "checked";  ?>>
        <?php _e( 'No', 'prfx-textdomain' )?>
    </label>
</div>
</p>

<?php
}

/**
* Saves the custom meta input
*/

// Pending a fix from WordPress- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16972
function prfx_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'prfx_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

// Checks for input and saves if needed
if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-radio' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-radio', $_POST[ 'meta-radio' ] );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';

global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
get_post_meta( $post->ID, $_POST['meta-radio'], true );
$response_radio = $_POST['meta-radio'];

if ($response_radio=="radio-one") {
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this');
    function add_this() {
    echo "The Yes button is selected...";  
}  
} elseif ($response_radio=="radio-two"){  
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this');
    function add_this() {
    echo "The No button is selected...";
} 
} else {
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this');
    function add_this() {
    echo "No data is passing...";
}
}
```

The result is "No data is passing..." when viewing a live page (even though the data is saving in the meta box).

**Edit-**
I added:
`echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';`

Below:
`add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );`

Output (editor and published page):
`Array
(
)`

Comment: Can you dump out $_POST for us, because your code looks fine. In that last `check_this`, add `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: I added it below `add_action( 'save_post', 'prfx_meta_save' );`. Please let me know if that's incorrect. Looks like I'm returning an empty array..

Comment: Ah, I wanted to see that output. Its just some debugging code that shows us exactly what is going on in your `$_POST`. Could you add that output to your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
$response_radio = $_POST['meta-radio'];  

if ($response_radio=="radio-one")  {
    //do your stuff
} elseif ($response_radio=="radio-two") {
    //do other stuff
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for